# javascript disabling unselected check box

Tags: javascript, select

i am having n number check box, if i checked one check box it has to select all the similar values of the check box and the other check box should be disable.

can any one help me to solve the issue

i am having a java script for select similar values selection

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function()
{
 var allInps = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), allCb = [];

 for( var i in allInps )
  if( allInps[ i ].type === 'checkbox' )
  {
   allCb.push( allInps[ i ] );   
   allInps[ i ].onclick = likeMe;
  }

 function likeMe()
 {
  for( var i in allCb )
   if( allCb[ i ] !== this && allCb[ i ].value === this.value )
    allCb[ i ].checked = this.checked;  
 }  

})();
</script>
```

please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines aren't needed: 
     (function()
    {
and this line:
    })();

To disable a checkbox, checkbox.disabled = true; (where checkbox is the element you want to disable)

In your likeMe function, add an else statement that disables the checkbox if they aren't similar.

I think that should work. here is how your code should be like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function()
{
 var allInps = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), allCb = [];

 for( var i in allInps )
  if( allInps[ i ].type === 'checkbox' )
  {
   allCb.push( allInps[ i ] );   
   allInps[ i ].onclick = likeMe;
  }

 function likeMe()
 {
  for(var i in allCb )
   if( allCb[ i ] !== this && allCb[ i ].id === this.id )
    allCb[ i ].checked = this.checked;
    else if (allCb[ i ].checked !== this.checked && allCb[ i ].id !== this.id )
    { 
     allCb[ i ].setAttribute('disabled',true);
   } 
   else { 
     allCb[ i ].removeAttribute('disabled');
   }
 }

})();
```

I think it will solve it.